# Concating a char[] and a *char[]

Tags: c, string, char, strcat

I have a `char` array

```
    char DATA[] = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: pipedream.net\r\nContent-Type: 
    application/json\r\nContent-Length: 28\r\n\r\n{\"key\": \"\"}";
```

There is a function

```
char *retKey(char key[]){
   // Some processing
   return key;
}
```

how do I concatenate the key returned from `retKey()` function to the earlier mentioned `DATA`? It should essentially look like this

```
char DATA[] = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: pipedream.net\r\nContent-Type: 
    application/json\r\nContent-Length: 28\r\n\r\n{\"key\": \"<key returned from retKey>\"}";
```

To make the final POST request, I tried

```
char DATA[] = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: pipedream.net\r\nContent-Type: 
    application/json\r\nContent-Length: 28\r\n\r\n{\"key\": \"\"}";
char key[16];
retKey(key);
strcat(DATA, key);
```

but I get some garbage output in the end after `DATA[]`.

Comment: some minimal example would be good to suggest anything

Comment: what example are you looking for ? i modified the code a bit

Comment: I'd put a `%s` in `DATA` where you want to insert the key and use it as a format string to `sprintf`. If you just add to the end your key will be outside the quotes and closing brace.

Comment: `strcat` will add at the end of another string, but looks like from your example you want to add key in between `\"\"` that is not exactly at the end of your DATA, but few chars before end

Comment: The answer by @sergeballesta gives me the output but the key generated shows up as garbage values

Comment: The garbage value, is likely the correct key as char[] values but interpreted as string (ascii/unicode utf16/utf8/or so). Try to hexdump the result to check, or convert to base64 to see some text.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store any concatenated output to `DATA`, as it's size is determined by the initializer string, and cannot be modified.

You need to either

- use a separate buffer, of length of minimum (length of `DATA` + length of the string to be appended + 1)
- define the `DATA` array with a big enough size so that it can hold the concatenated output.

After that, I think rather concatenation, you need a formatted substitution. You should form a string with a conversion specifier, like

```
 char DATA[] = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: pipedream.net\r\nContent-Type: 
application/json\r\nContent-Length: 28\r\n\r\n{\"key\": \"%s\"}";
```

and then, use `sprintf()` to print this to another buffer, with the value, like

```
char dest[256];                //select the size based on your final output
sprintf(dest, data, retKey(key)); // assuming retkey(key); call returns the value for key
```

Comment: if i use a seperate buffer say RES[], then how would i concatenate DATA[] + key[] into RES[]

Comment: @omkarjoglekar just provided a sample code (not tested, pseudocode)

Comment: the retKey function returns a pointer  char *retKey(char key[]){
   // Some processing
   return key;
}

Comment: Also i think i will need concatination as this string needs to be send ahead on a UART buffer. Just sprint would help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate string with `strcat`, provided the char array is large enough to accept the new characters. If it is not, you should allocate a new array large enough to contain the result:

```
char * newkey = retkey(key);
char *data = malloc(1 + strlen(newkey) + strlen(DATA);
strcpy(data, DATA);
data[strlen(data) - 2] = '\0';    //remove last to characters ("})
strcat(data, newkey);
strcat(data, "\"}");              // add them back after the key
...    // use data
free(data);
```

Beware, tests for correct allocation are omitted here for brievety, but should be required for real world programming.

Comment: the retKey() function returns a pointer.  I get the output as below when i print data.                                                                         
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: pipedream.net
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 28

{"key": "ÿ.fsl_clock.c:468 : false:©ÅvÙJ"}

Comment: The placement of the key is correct but the key shows up as garbage value.

Comment: I cannot know what **your** `retkey` function is expected to return. Did you control that?

Comment: the retKey() returns a * char key[16]

Comment: When you call `retkey` in your own code, what is the return value, and is it what you expect?

Comment: @omkarjoglekar: what I am asking you is if you can **print** that value...

Comment: If I print it in a for loop as for { printf(key[I]} I do see the values. But if I just printf(key) I get gibberish.

Comment: @omkarjoglekar: then use `strcat(data, key[I]);` instead of   `strcat(data, newkey);`. But without knowing *exactly* how you can find the keys, I cannot say more.

Comment: Ok I will try it. I am AFK for few hours.